# How to test for variance between conditions

Tags: variance, categorical-data, excel, biostatistics

I have some Nanostring results that depict the fold change in expression after various conditions are applied.  The people I am working with would like to know how to see what conditions give the largest change.  For example which genes have the largest variance between all of the conditions and which genes have the largest variance between only a few of the conditions, i.e., between condition 1 and 2.  What I have done was a simple test of variance across the 4 conditions, using the var.s function in Excel

Here is a link to the Excel function [var.s](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/var-s-function-HP010335702.aspx).

Here is a small example:

```
Gene Name   Tconv WT/Treg WT    Tconv DEL/Treg WT   Tconv WT/Treg DEL   Tconv DEL/Treg DEL
ACVR2A      1                    1.07               -1.02                1.01
AHR         1                    1.48                1.26                1.72
AchE        1                    1.51               -1.46               -3.32
Adrb2       1                   -1.13                1.04               -1.19
Arg1        1                    1.1                -1.61               -1.14
Arnt1       1                    1.07               -1.03                1.08
Arnt2       1                    1.53                1.3                 1.3
```

All of the fold change data can be found on pastbin [here](http://pastebin.com/CQ8k5Vfb).

The question I have is, is this even the best test to do for this, and if I wanted to then look for the largest variation between condition 1 and 2 for example, as well as all of the other combinations can I still use the same test?

Comment: In what sense do you mean "variance"? There is the Analysis Of Variance (ANOVA), which tests if there are differences in *means* among several conditions; & there are tests to see if the *variances* themselves differ among several conditions (eg, Levene's test).

Comment: @gung so far I have just tried using the VAR.S function in excel, which estimates variance based on a sample (ignores logical values and text in the sample). I calculated this for the 4 sample conditions for each gene.

Comment: So do you want to know which condition has the largest variance (or, more likely, if 1 of the conditions was drawn from a different population w/ larger variance than the rest)? Do you not care if 1 condition was sampled from a population w/ a different *mean* from the rest?

Comment: @gung, I'm sorry for making the question unclear, I will also update the question.  I want to know which genes have the largest variance across all 4 conditions and for which genes is there the largest variance between conditions.  For example if the variance between condition 1 and 2 are larger for gene A then gene B.

Comment: @gung I think that the samples may well have different means, it does not bother me per say unless it means that I can't calculate variance for a sample across conditions.